# AWS Route 53 configuration problems for S3 hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a static site hosted on S3, mylifeinlimbo.ca

I have set up S3 with a bucket for www.mylifeinlimbo.ca which redirects to the main bucket and created an 'A' record in Route 53 ([see image for settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ncrF.png)). This seems to be working fine.

However, I would also like a staging site with some additional functionality at staging.mylifeinlimbo.ca. I have tried to duplicate the same setup as the 'www' bucket but have had varying degrees of success (changing the subdomain to a CNAME, etc). At one point the http version was working and the https wasn't but now I think they're both down.

Route 53 will not allow a trailing dot on the staging alias unlike the 'default' and 'www' domains. Could that be the issue?

This is the endpoint for the staging bucket: http://staging.mylifeinlimbo.ca.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: The http version of staging is working.

Comment: Oh that's good to know, thank you! Would you know why http://staging.mylifeinlimbo.ca would work but https://staging.mylifeinlimbo.ca doesn't?

Comment: >Amazon S3 does not support HTTPS access to the website. If you want to use HTTPS, you can use Amazon CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: Ok I'm trying that now thanks!